# Pass callback function from parent component to child component react

Tags: reactjs

**GOAL:** Send callback function from parent to child to toggle sidebar component.

This code opens the sidebar:

```
<Sidebar show={status} />

  <button onClick={() => setStatus((status) => !status)}>
      <SettingsIcon/>
  </button>
```

I use both true and false values for `status` to toggle the sidebar on and off.

Now, in my sidebar component, I need to pass a `false` value to `show` so that is closes when my `Back` button is clicked.

```
const Sidebar = ({ show }) => {
  const { left } = useSpring({
    from: { left: "-100%" },
    left: show ? "0" : "-100%",
  });

  return (
    <animated.div
      style={{
        left: left,
        position: "absolute",
        height: "100%",
        width: "55%",
        backgroundColor: "black",
        zIndex: 1,
      }}
      className="Sidebar"
    >
      <button onClick={() => !show}>Back</button>
      <p>hello</p>
    </animated.div>
  );
};
```

I can't seem to get it working. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Sounds pretty basic. Why don't you just pass a reference to the `setStatus` function into `Sidebar`? Something like this: `const Sidebar = ({ show, setStatus }) => {`. Then change your button to `<button onClick={() => setStatus(!show)}>`

Comment: Also, just FYI, you can change the `onClick` in your parent component to `onClick={() => setStatus(!status)}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the parent state from a child component you can pass a callback to the child as a prop that sets the state using the setStatus function like this:

```
<Sidebar show={status} onSidebarClick={() => setStatus(!status)} />
```

And in your sidebar component you just need to do this:

```
const Sidebar = ({ show, onSidebarClick }) => {
  // Your code

  return (
   {/* Rest of your JSX */}
    <button onClick={onSidebarClick}>Back</button>
  )
}
```

You should pass the callback function from the parent and use the setStatus function to perform the change. Do not try to do the change by yourself without the setStatus function.