# call function from parent with structure. <App><Parent><Child></Child></Parent><App>

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react. Basically I want that when I click on the button of the child component, respecting this structure:

```
<Parent>
  <Child/>
<Parent>
```

the function `myFunction` is called from the parent component. How can I do it?

This is my live code

```
import "./styles.css";
export const Parent = ({ children }) => {
  //I need excecute myFunction when user click
  return (
    <div>
      I am parent <br />
      <br /> {children}
    </div>
  );
};
export const Child = () => {
  const myFunction = () => {
    console.log("say hello from parent");
  };
  return (
    <div>
      I am children
      <br />
      <button>Send function to execute in the parent</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Parent>
      <Child />
    </Parent>
  );
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "called from the parent component"?  The function is in the child component.  How is the parent component involved at all?  It's not really clear to me what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @david call myFunction in the parent

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to pass a callback function prop to the child component

Look here [callback function from parent to child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65895361/pass-callback-function-from-parent-component-to-child-component-react)

Comment: I am new, can you help me with my code please? it is very difficult :(