# How can I pass a function to a child component from a function component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, storybook

I've got a template component that takes children and renders it, I want to have a function in that component that is available to the children components passed to it

Currently I've got this:

```
const Template = ({ 
  children,
}) => {
  const myFunction = () => {
    alert("test");
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        {children}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export const MyStory: Story = {
  render: args => (
    <Template>
      my children
    </Template>
  )
}
```

I want to be able to use "MyFunction" within where MyStory renders the template, something like this:

```
export const MyStory: Story = {
  render: args => (
    <Template>
      {({ myFunction }) => {
        return (
          <>
            My children

            <button onClick={myFunction}>click me</button>
          </>
        )
      }}
    </Template>
  )
}
```

Is there any way to do this? I've seen it done when children is passed directly to the template but this isn't the case here, there's some wrapper jsx needed.
I've also seen it done when using Formik, it allows the children to use Formik functions.

If anyone could help id greatly appreciate it!

Comment: isn't this what you are trying to achieve: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65895361/pass-callback-function-from-parent-component-to-child-component-react

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```javascript
const Template = ({ children }) => {
  const myFunction = () => {
    alert('test');
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {React.Children.map(children, child =>
        React.cloneElement(child, { myFunction })
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

const ChildComponent = ({ myFunction }) => {
  return (
    <>
      My children
      <button onClick={myFunction}>click me</button>
    </>
  );
};

export const MyStory = {
  render: args => (
    <Template>
      <ChildComponent />
    </Template>
  ),
};
```